# Ionic framework - landscape split view ghost

Tags: ionic-framework, landscape-portrait

I'm developing an app based on Ionic framework, targeted for phones (portrait mode) and tablets (landscape mode). In landscape mode I'm using Ionic's '[expose-aside-when'](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/exposeAsideWhen/) to always display the menu at the left side. The weird thing is, that there is kind of a ghost menu at the right side – its width is exactly 275px and it's just white background. See this image for reference, the blue area is the exposed side menu, the red area is the content, the white area is the ghost spacing I'd like to get rid of: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUvLO.png)

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind folks, I've found the problem. There were two ion-side-menu directives which were conditionally hidden, based on tablet recognition – which was not ready when the DOM was loaded, so both of the ion-side-menus were there during calculation of the main content – therefore the white space at the right side.